# Not able to make responsive design due to "margin" as inline css

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I am designing a page that needs to be rendered in large, medium and small screens responsively. I am using Material ui Grid container and inside that displaying `Chips` with `style={{ marginLeft: 60 }}` from second chip onward to keep a distance between first-second,second-third and so on but as soon as my screen size changes, these chips are getting overlapped on each other but no responsive behavior. Below is my code

```
 <Grid container item xs={12}>
            <Grid container item xs={11}>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Chip/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={2} style={{ marginLeft: 60 }}>
                  <Chip/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={2} style={{ marginLeft: 60 }}>
                   <Chip/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={2} style={{ marginLeft: 60 }}>
                     <Chip/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={2} style={{ marginLeft: 57 }}>
                     <Chip/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How to get my design correct? Please suggest. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring static margin sizes in pixels which will not shrink with the screen size.  Either change them to relative sizes (e.g., `style={{ marginLeft: '5%' }}`), or assign the grids a `className` property and use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) in your CSS file to set breakpoints at the required screen sizes.

The latter option will provide you with much more control if responsiveness is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me out to right path, just curious though how can the design adjust to screen sizes like `xs`, `md`, etc